# Difference between a retag and an inline tag edit?

Tags: discussion, privileges

The privileges information pages informs you that when you reach a reputation of 500, you are granted the privilege of being able to retag questions without peer reviewing (using the retag link under the question):

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions

When you reach a reputation of 10000 you are granted the privilege of inline tag edits, which seems to be the same thing, but the retag link has been removed and instead you hover the mouse to the right of the tags:

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools (see bottom of the page)

What's the difference between retaging and inline tag edits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None.

Inline tag editing is just an easier and quicker way of doing it. It was made a reward and put with the 10k tools.

Note that with 2k+, you must actually edit the post to edit tags; there is no "retag" button. That makes the privelege all the more convenient.

Comment: Why is the retag link removed for 2k+ users? It seems to me like it would be a good feature to keep even for 2k+ users as it is smoother than having to see the whole edit page for the post if you just want to retag. As it also bypasses the review queue it simply does not make any sense to remove it?

Comment: @Daniel 1.) That might make a good [feature-request] `:)` 2.) Users with 2k+ have their edits automatically accepted; they don't go through a review queue.

Comment: I posted a feature request. We'll see how it is received.

Comment: @Daniel Great! I upvoted it

Comment: Just tested to verify- inline tag editing does bump the post and appears in the edit history like any other edit