# Inline tag edits don't show my edit until the page is refreshed

Tags: bug, tags, edits

I often use the [inline tag editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171578/202832) on Stack Overflow. However, the "Edited [time] ago" box below doesn't appear until *after* the page is refreshed. This is different than the behavior if I use the `edit` link; doing this will show "edited [time] ago" immediately. Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Missed that... Voted as duplicate.